# How to resize div height to match height of image within it

Tags: javascript, html

Using Javascript how do I set a div height to automatically match the height of the image that is set to width 100% contained within it when I view in responsive view?

Comment: Don't set a height on the div that's containing the image - it will naturally shrink and grow to accommodate it's content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things I would suggest trying:

1) the unslider lib should automatically adjust to your height, according to their site: [unslider](http://unslider.com).

2) have you set image height: `height: 100%`?

Also try setting the 'float' property on the images ie `float: left`. You'll be surprised how much that stuff helps.

Answer (score 3):

You need a bit of css:

```
div.imageContainer {
  overflow:auto;
}
```

Make sure height is not set on the div, and make sure the image is not positioned absolutely within the div.  You don't need javascript for this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code:

```
<div class="banner">

<ul>
<li><img src="resources/images/header1.jpg" style="width:100%;"></li>
<li><img src="resources/images/header2.jpg" style="width:100%;"></li>
<li><img src="resources/images/header3.jpg" style="width:100%;"></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

basically the banner div doesnt reduce in size to match the height of the image as it gets smaller many thanks again for all your help